# Multiple layers processing mouse input, instead of only the top layer clicked

Tags: libgdx, input, mouse

Rectangles are grouped and attached to a "layer" extending Stage.
Each layer is added to a multiplexer in a Screen extension.

There are 2 layers:

- Top has the 1 big rectangle & group members (smaller colored rectangles)
- Bottom has the 2 big rectangles & their members

The 3 big rectangles are all the same size & color (turns yellow if it detects the mouse is over it, for debugging purposes)

When you click on it, it brings its **group** to the front of its **layer**.

The problem is that both the top layer and bottom layer are processing the input, though grouping and drawing stuff works fine.

In the screenshot, only the top-most big rectangle should be yellow at the cursor's position:

[image: Two yellow rectangles overlapping, and one white rectangle]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using some kind of `Event`, you should mark that the Event as "handled" to prevent it being propagated further.

You can do this in the Actor by calling `Event.handle()`.

If you are using the Stage methods, you should also be able to do this by returning `true` from (eg) `Stage.mouseMoved`. This will indicate that the input has been processed and does not need to be sent to other objects.